# Where are the symmetric keys stored?

Tags: linux, gnupg

I don't seem to find the option to save symmetric keys. What I want to do is that I simply want to encrypt a file and transfer the file and the symmetric key (which is encrypted with the recipients public key). But so far I have not found any way to actually access the key file for symmetric keys. Do you know how I can access it?

Comment: *Why* do you want to access it?

Comment: I want to perform a hybrid encryption using gpg.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is [actually how PGP/GPG operates](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x209.html).

When you encrypt something to a public key, it first encrypts the data with a symmetric key. Then it encrypts the symmetric key with public key cryptography, and appends it to the encrypted data.

Assymmetric encryption is not suitable for big amounts of data, due to speed of encryption. Thus this improves speed of encryption.

In addition, it allows for multiple recipients of the data without significant increase in size; only the symmetric key has to be encrypted for each recipient, while the bulk data can be included only once.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Now I understand why there are no articles about how to access symmetric keys because it's not necessary (at least in most cases I guess). It's very nice to hear that it works that way. This makes the process of using hybrid encryption much easier!

Comment: For many forms of public key crypto, this is the *only* way to do things. The public key algorithm does not encrypt anything but instead serves as a *key exchange* process. This is the case for anything Diffie-Hellman-like, including ECDH (EC = elliptic curve) where the product of your ephemeral secret and the recipient's public key is the same as the product of your ephemeral public (which you transmit) and the recipient's secret and serves as key material for a symmetric cipher.

Comment: And while the DEK is normally only 'saved' in the message, encrypted, you _can_ extract it: see `--show-session-key` in https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Esoteric-Options.html